# Convergence of a linear combination of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

How do I prove that if $X_n\to X$ and $Y_n\to Y$ in $L^2$ then $aX_n+bY_n\to aX+bY$ in $L^2$?

I can begin as follows, $$E((aX_n+bY_n-(aX+bY))^2)=a^2E((X_n-X)^2)+2abE((X_n-X)(Y_n-Y))+b^2E((Y_n-Y)^2).$$ Evidently the first and last terms go to $0$, but what can I conclude about the second term? If $X_n-X$ and $Y_n-Y$ are independent then I can conclude that the covariance is $0$, but they are not necessarily independent. Am I supposed to use Cauchy-Schwarz in some way?

Comment: True in any normed linear space. You only need triangle inequality for the $L^{2}$ norm. You can also complete your argument by applying Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for the middle term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work out with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for the expectation. We can make the estimate $|E((X_n-X)(Y_n-Y))|\leq \sqrt{E(|X_n-X|^2)E(|Y_n-Y|^2)}$ which then also goes to $0$.